# How to customize horizontal scroll thumb in UWP ScrollViewer

Tags: uwp, xamarin.uwp, windows-community-toolkit

Suggestion required to customize the color and width horizontal scroll thumb in UWP ScrollViewer. I have tried to customize the scroll thumb as mentioned in the below forum,

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/476b95de-896c-4117-96aa-6e7365e3defe/uwp-xaml-chanaging-the-thumb-color-of-scrollbarscrollviewer?forum=wpdevelop

However, it seems to work only for vertical thumb only.

Answer (score 1):

By testing, the way that setting SolidColorBrush of your mentioned link works well, which also works on horizontal scroll thumb.

For the width of thumb, you could change it through `ViewportSize`.
Please check the following steps:

1. Open the **Document Outline pane**, right-click your ScrollViewer control.
2. Choose the option **Edit Template > Edit a Copy**. Then a default style of the ScrollViewer control will be applied to your ScrollViewer control.
3. Find the ScrollBar control named `HorizontalScrollBar`. Then change the ViewportSize.

Please refer to the following code:

```
<Page …>
<Page.Resources>       
  <Style x:Key="ScrollViewerStyle1" TargetType="ScrollViewer">
    …….
      <ScrollBar x:Name="HorizontalScrollBar" IsTabStop="False" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" ViewportSize="10" Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
       …….
      </Style>
   </Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ScrollViewer Style="{StaticResource ScrollViewerStyle1}" 
              HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
              Height="200" Width="200">
            <ScrollViewer.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBarThumbFill" Color="Gold"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBarThumbFillPointerOver" Color="Orange"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBarThumbFillPressed" Color="Red"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBarThumbFillDisabled" Color="Pink"/>
            </ScrollViewer.Resources>
            <Image Source="Assets/testP.jpg" Height="400" Width="400"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```